# Encode String as Copy Safe Value

Tags: rust

String cannot impliment `Copy`. But what if we to use a String in our Struct or Enum without loosing `Copy`.

Would it be possible to encode the String into a Copy safe type, like `i32`?

```rust
//Error String does not impl Copy
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum MyEnum{
    Integer32(i32),
    Unsized32(u32),
    SomeString(String),
}
```

```rust
//Copy works, our string can be encoded
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum MyEnum{
    Integer32(i32),
    Unsized32(u32),
    SomeEncodeString(i32),
}


fn decode_enum_to_string(e: MyEnum)->Result<String, Error>{
    //returns a result with our decoded string value, or an error 
    //if the decoding fails
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to embed a non-`Copy` type in a `Copy` type.  You can use `Clone` instead.

Comment: This is what I feared/suspected. Its just that using clone will require a lot of painful boilerplate and ```clone()``` ops to be added.

Comment: `Copy` translates to a simple `memcpy` under the hood.  In the Rust mode of thinking, cloning is as much an operation as any other method.  If proper usage of `.clone()` really causes "a lot of painful boilerplate", that may indicate performance issues with the code, so don't avoid cloning just for the sake of it.

Comment: You could consider using a &str instead of a String.